# Calling Serial Port Class from a JFrame Class

Tags: java, constructor, serial-port

I am experimenting with Java's JFrame with an Arduino through the serial port and I ran into a problem, I'm not sure how to continue with my code.

I'm trying to call the serial port portion of one class from my JFrame code in another class using constructors. Basically, I am trying to connect my Java program with the Arduino Uno.

**My problem is that when I try to run the code from the GUI class, at the *SerialOut.write("test".getBytes());*, an error says "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException".**

**Can someone look at the constructor and tell me if I have made any mistakes? Thanks!**

Class for setting up the Serial Port This code by itself works [I test it using an Uno and a LED to see if it lights up. (It does)]

```
package javaapplication1;

import javaapplication1.RCDA_JFrame;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier; 
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent; 
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener; 
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SerialTest implements SerialPortEventListener {
        //constructor
        public SerialTest(){
            this.initialize();
            this.close();
            this.serialEvent(null);
        }        
    SerialPort serialPort;
        /** The port we're normally going to use. */
    private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
            "COM8",}; // Windows 
    private BufferedReader input;
    private static OutputStream SerialOut;/** The output stream to the port */
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;/** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;/** Default bits per second for COM port. */

    public void initialize() {
        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                    portId = currPortId;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (portId == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                    TIME_OUT);

            // set port parameters
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            // open the streams
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
            SerialOut = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            // add event listeners
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
    /**
     * This should be called when you stop using the port.
     * This will prevent port locking on platforms like Linux.
     */
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }
    }
    //Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine=input.readLine();
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SerialTest main = new SerialTest();
        main.initialize();
        Thread t=new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000 seconds,
                //waiting for events to occur and responding to them (printing incoming messages to console).
                try {Thread.sleep(1000000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
        };
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Started");
        //testing
                try {
                System.out.println("This is a test");
                System.out.println("test".getBytes());
                SerialOut.write("test".getBytes()); //SEND STRING THROUGH SERIAL PORT
        } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
        } //end of testing
    }
}
```

JFrame class - where I am trying to call the class above:

```
package javaapplication1;

import javaapplication1.SerialTest;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier; 
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent; 
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener; 
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.io.IOException;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame implements SerialPortEventListener {

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent ev) {
    SerialTest ST1 = new SerialTest();
    }
    private static OutputStream SerialOut;
    SerialPort serialPort;
        /** The port we're normally going to use. */
//    private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
//          "COM8"}; // Windows 
//    private BufferedReader input;
//    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;/** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
//    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;/** Default bits per second for COM port. */
//    
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

public static void main(String args[]) {
        //constructor from SerialTest
        SerialTest ST1 = new SerialTest();

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        try {
            System.out.println("This is a test");
            System.out.println("test".getBytes());
              SerialOut.write("test".getBytes()); //SEND STRING THROUGH SERIAL PORT
            } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @EJP, my question is how do I call my SerialTest class from my JFrame class? (I want to set up the serial communication from my JFrame class so I could do stuff with using a GUI and the serial port)

Comment: Clear as mud until you actually provided the exception 12 hours later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error check to see if the port is null after it goes through the list of available ports. Make sure that it is indeed getting the available ports, and that you do have a value getting assigned to it.

```
if (portId == null) {
     System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
     return;
}
```

To confirm try printing out the portName to see what port it actually is getting like so `portId.getName()` and check to make sure it's not null. If it is, there's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static OutputStream SerialOut;/** The output stream to the port */
```

This is in `SerialTest.` NB it should not be static. It is initialized when you call `initialize()`, provided a port was found, and as `initialize()` doesn't throw exceptions or return any status it is impossible to know whether it has succeed. Fix that.

```
private static OutputStream SerialOut;
```

That's in `NewJFrame`. It isn't the same data item as the previous one. It is never initialized at all, so it is null, so you get a `NullPointerException`. Remove it, and use the one in `SerialTest.`

Comment: Thanks @EJP, I have an update and a question for you:

--I tried removing the _static_ label from my `SerialTest` code but when I run the code by itself, I cannot call a non-static from static context (main function).

--Am I initializing this correctly?
in `SerialTest`: inside the constructor, I put OutputStream SerialOut;
in `NewJFrame` after SerialTest ST1 = new SerialTest(); -- I put SerialOut = SerialOut.SerialTest();

Comment: I didn't say to remove the `static`. I said to remove *it.* The whole thing. Please read what I actually wrote.